# yii: How to publish a widget's directory (folder)

Tags: php, yii

I have a component `datetimepicker` with assets folders `js`,`css` and `img` which are not empty:

```
application/components
application/components/datetimepicker/assets
application/components/datetimepicker/assets/js
application/components/datetimepicker/assets/css
application/components/datetimepicker/assets/img
```

I try to publish entire `assets` folder with one call to `publish` method from `yii` `Asset Manager`:

```
$assetsPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('datetimepicker.assets');
$assetsUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assetsPath, false, -1, true);
```

But it doesn't publish anything. All folders and files under `application/` folder have write and read permissions. Can anybody help, please?

P.S. I made sure that `Yii::getPathOfAlias('datetimepicker.assets')` returns the right path and `Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assetsPath, false, -1, true)` returns reasonable string  - `/assets/d4a0c9d8`. Also `yii` copies whole `application/components/datetimepicker/assets/` directory to `application/assets` under the name `d4a0c9d8` - `application/assets/d4a0c9d8`, but in links to the files in this folder  are generated in the html output file.

Comment: Try: `application.components.datetimepicker.assets` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I misunderstood the conception of Assets Manager. The `publish` method only copies files from the custom widget's directory to the main `assests` directory. (i.e. `to publish` == `to copy`) And you still need to register the scripts and css files to point out their order. Right?

Example

```
public function registerAssetJs($jsFile, $position = NULL)
{
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile($this->getAssetsUrl() . "/js/{$jsFile}", $position);
}

public function registerAssetCss($cssFile, $media = '')
{
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile($this->getAssetsUrl() . "/css/{$cssFile}", $media);
}   

public function getAssetsUrl()
{
    if (isset($this->_assetsUrl))
        return $this->_assetsUrl;
    else
    {
        $assetsPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('datetimepicker.assets');
        $assetsUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assetsPath, false, -1, YII_DEBUG);
        return $this->_assetsUrl = $assetsUrl;
    }
}
```